# Do some Android mobile devices not have a touch identifier in the event?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, touch-event

Do some devices (maybe tablets) actually not have a touch identifier? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch.identifier)

I am trying to debug an error reported by a small number of users via my automated reporting system. The stack trace tells me that the touch event identifier is sometimes undefined. I haven't logged the identifiers yet to know that for sure.

I'm using Chrome 41.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar experiences.
Touch event sometimes gives undefined that is because there are no identifiers.
For instance, when you try to get targetTouches[0].identifier on touchend event and all touches have already left, then it will return undefined.
In this case you have to use changedTouches rather than targetTouches.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks. I will take a look and see if there's anything in changedTouches... will post here what I find out.